# If a cyclotomic polynomial factors into powers of irreducible factors modulo a prime, then the factors have the same degree and multiplicity

Tags: solution-verification, algebraic-number-theory

Is this correct? This is a problem I came up with:

> Let $\phi_n$ be the $n$-th cyclotomic polynomial. Suppose that $\phi_n$ splits into powers of $d$ irreducible factors $\mod p$ for some prime $p$. Show that all these factors have the same degree and multiplicity.

Solution: By neukirch ch1 prop 8.3 the splitting of $\phi_n$ mod p corresponds to the splitting of (p) in $\mathcal{O}_k$ with degree of an irreducible factor corresponding to the inertia degree of the prime factor and the multiplicity corresponding to the ramification index of that prime factor. We can invoke this because the conductor of $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta]$ is just $\mathcal{O}_k$ since $\mathcal{O}_k = \mathbb{Z}[\zeta]$. But $\mathcal{O}_k$ is coprime to all ideals so we can use this prop. But since the cyclotomic fields are Galois the primes over (p) all have equal ramification indices and inertia degrees. The conclusion follows.

We also see that the following. let d be the number of factors and e be the multiplicity of $p_1(x)$ and $f$ be the degree of $p_1(x)$ with $p_1(x)$ being an irreducible factor. Then $d*e*f=\phi(n)$ with $\phi$ the totient function. This comes from the fundamental identity.

Lastly it seems that Hensel's lemma implies this is true for $\mathbb{Z}_p$ when the multiplicity is one in the mod p reduction.

Ugh.. I just realized that neukirch proved a stronger statement in prop 10.3 of chapter 1.

Comment: This seems good to me. A similar argument should work when $\phi_n$ is replaced by any polynomial $f$ such that $K=\mathbb Q[X]/(f)$ is Galois, and $p$ is large enough so that $p\nmid [\mathcal O_K: \mathbb Z[\alpha]]$.

Comment: Nice because only finitely many primes are not coprime to the conductor of $\mathbb{ℤ}[$].

Comment: By conductor I mean the conductor ideal.